# Mysql: How to get update rows incrementally when there are missing id's?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that all have a unique ID. They are in ascending order, and I would like to do..

```
update text SET name = 'hello french man' where id=1;
```

And change the name of every row to this data I have. So I can keep incrementing

```
id = id + 1;
```

But the problem occurs here, I've deleted some rows in the past, so there are missing IDs. For instance, there's row 1,2,3,5. Row 4 is missing because I had deleted it, so how can I update every row without skipping a name because updating row 4 won't do anything?

It is crucial that I have a 1-1 mapping with all of them and do not skip any names since order matters.

Thanks, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I missunderstand something. Do you want to update every record to say 'hello french man'?

Comment: No, that's an example, each name will have their own value. ^_^

Comment: Are you looking to actually increment the id of every row in the table by +1 or do you want to update it in such a way that there is no sequential gaps in the `id` field (e.g. `1,2,3,5,8` becomes `1,2,3,4,5`) ?

Comment: A very simple (but non-optimized) solution would be to first do `SELECT ID` and then iterate over the list of IDs that gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
UPDATE tbl a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
    FROM tbl
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) var_init
    ORDER BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id, @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rn
    FROM tbl
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=-1) var_init
    ORDER BY id
) c ON b.rn = c.rn
SET a.id = COALESCE(c.id, a.id + 1)
```

---

### [See the SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad398/1/0)

Comment: Would that still work if 'id' is set to 3, but the row with id='3' was deleted, so that no longer exists.

Comment: @unwiseguy look at the [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d86/1/0) It works even when there are sequential gaps in the `id` field.

Comment: Not by +1, only incrementing to the next existing id. So if the ID's were 1,3,4. The next ID from 1 would be 3 and not 2.

Comment: @unwiseguy Okay, now I see what you mean.

Comment: yes, each name would be different. I would be calling these update statements sequentially.

Comment: @unwiseguy, see my updated solution. It updates the `id` to the next highest `id` in the data in ascending order. If the `id` is the last sequential `id`, it just updates it by +1.